# How to combine accordion with connected sortable lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to put jquery-ui sortable list inside accordion sections and connect those lists. The idea is to create a compact and intuitive interface for sorting items in a few different categories. Items are usually sorted within one section, but sometimes they may be carrried into another accordion section.

I am *almost* there: http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/H5MRw/7/

Here is a sample of the HTML code:

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3 class="accordion-header"><a href="#">good</a></h3>
   <div class="accordion-section">
       <ul class="sortable-list">
           <li>dog</li>
           <li>butter</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
// Setup the accordion
$("#accordion").accordion();
var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();

//Setup the sortable list
$("ul.sortable-list").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.sortable-list", // connect all sortable lists together so items can be dragged from one list to aother
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("an item was moved");
    }
}).disableSelection();

$("h3.accordion-header").droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        //it would be ideal to have some sort of tollorance or delay so user does not accidentally expand another section or accordion
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        $accordion.accordion('activate', $(this));
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    }
});
```

The part that is not working yet is showing user the correct visual feedback while an item is being dragged from one list to another. When user drags an item on top of the header for another accordion section, that section is activated, however, for some reason the element used during the drag somehow disappears. The item is actually still there and if you proceed to drop it into the list you can see the placeholder shows up and you can drop the item into the new location.

How can I fix this implementation so the user can see the item they are dragging even when they go to another section of the accordion. I would appreciate any help in solving this problem, but please use [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/H5MRw/7/) I provided to demonstrate your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the problem is the dragged element belongs to the `div accordion-section`. When you hover another section the current div will be hide with the dragged element.

So to solve the problem, you can create a `ul temporary` to store the dragged element. This `ul` will be remove at the end of drag event.

**Javascript:**

```
// Setup the accordion
//$("#accordion").accordion();
var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();

//Setup the sortable list
$("ul.sortable-list").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.sortable-list", // connect all sortable lists together so items can be dragged from one list to aother
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("an item was moved");
        $accordion.find("#tmp").remove();
    },
    start: function(event, ui){
        $accordion.append("<ul id='tmp'></ul>");
        $accordion.find("#tmp").append(ui.item);
    }
}).disableSelection();

$("h3.accordion-header").droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
        //it would be ideal to have some sort of tollorance or delay so user does not accidentally expand another section or accordion
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        $accordion.accordion('activate', $(this));
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/gLVRB/1/) there is a fiddle example. I hope this code helps you but you may insist to move the dragged element I don't know why.

Comment: That is a legitimate solution and certainly does what I needed. Thank you very much!